# Visual studio 2010 ouput window maximize on build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there way to **automatically** maximize the output window on hitting build and then to automatically restore to previous state when the build completes?

Comment: I'm sure you can build a macro for it

Comment: You can configure Visual Studio to *show* the Output window on a build, and if expand it to fill 99% of the screen then unpin it, it should pop back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could implement a solution using a combination of macros.

Part of the solution is in this SO question:
[OnBuildBegin does not fire in Visual Studio Macro until I run it from Macro Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345467/onbuildbegin-does-not-fire-in-visual-studio-macro-until-i-run-it-from-macro-expl)

And the other part is to use 2 exported window settings and to toggle them on build events.

Something like:

```
Public Sub BuildEvents_OnBuildBegin() Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildBegin
      DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "-import:C:\Development\VsSettings\build_inprocess.vssettings")
End Sub

Private Sub BuildEvents_OnBuildDone(ByVal Scope As EnvDTE.vsBuildScope, ByVal Action As EnvDTE.vsBuildAction) _
    Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildDone
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "-import:C:\Development\VsSettings\Two_Screen.vssettings")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a macro that builds the solution then activates the output window.  For example:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.BuildSolution")
DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindOutput).Activate()
```

You could then replace the Build button or the build keyboard shortcut to execute that macro.

Comment: It does not do what I'm wanting to do. It would not re-size back to the original "o/p window" size on completing build operation and also won't work if the "o/p window" is floating.

Comment: You can't "maximize the output window (without it taking the whole screen (overtop of all of the VS window) when floating.  i.e. what happens when floating needs to be different than when it's docked.  so, you'd need to provide more detail to get exactly what you want.

Comment: My scenario is that I've 2 monitors, output window is on the right monitor and I need to maximize and minmize based on my build action. I'm looking at use window.height and window.width to achieve it, but not there yet.